# c++ finding a string using part of the string

Tags: c++

lets say that we have:

```
string list[]= {"12.34.56.78","55.34.5","23.44.5"}
```

I want the user to enter part of the string which is also a string:
for example string 55 and it will loop through the string a and look for the whole string and print `"55.34.5"`
What I was doing is:

`str` is a string input and `list` is a whole list of the strings

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
  for (int j=0; j<(list[i].length()); j++){
    for (int k=0; k<(str.length()); k++){
      if (list[i][j] == str[k])
        cout<<list[i]<<endl;
      else
        break;
```

however, there is a problem with this, and it doesn't work properly.

Update:

so I have updated my code to:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    if (strncmp(list[i].c_str(), str.c_str(), str.length()) == 0)){
      cout<<list[i]<<endl;
      }
```

however, this doesn't output any of the strings.

Comment: Think at a higher level... you have a [string class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) look at the member functions of this class and see if one provides what you need.

Comment: What if the user enters "34"? Do you want the first two strings to match ("12.34.56.78" and "55.34.5")?  In other words, are you looking for the user string to be a `substring` of a string in your list?

Comment: output both choices then

Comment: Wait, if your string is "abcdef", and the user enters "cde", is that a match, or does it have to match from the beginning?

Comment: basically like it is stated in the problem, that between dots have to be match in strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer that combines both of the previous answers. It uses the [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) member function of the `std::string` class

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    if (list[i].find(str) != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << list[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That just compares the first character in list[i] with the first char in your string. If the corresponding first chars match, it prints the entire ith string and then advances k, the offset into your str, without changing the offset into the string against which you're comparing. I think you can dispense with the inner two loops, and use a fixed length string comparison, i.e.,

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
  if (strncmp(list[i].c_str(), str.c_str(), str.length()) == 0) {
    // match
  }
}
```

Comment: how would you match it then though?

Comment: Good point, I need to compare the response from strncmp to zero - edit above.

Comment: it doesn't give me anything actually

Comment: `strncmp` will not find a substring unless they match from the start, use the `find` member function of `std::string` like `chris` showed in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

For any function fanatics ([see it work](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4d44b0253919cb9b9bbc31b7364bd372)):

```
std::string findInList(const std::vector<std::string> &searchFrom, const std::string &lookFor) {
    for (const std::string &s : searchFrom) {
        if (s.find(lookFor) != std::string::npos)
            return s;
    }

    return "";
}
```

I used a vector instead of an array because vectors are better and don't require extra work to get the array size from. If C++11 isn't being used, a normal for loop works perfectly fine.

This also assumes you want the first match to be returned. A probably better option is to return a vector of strings, empty if none are found, which makes it explicit that none were found, or as many as are found otherwise. Instead of returning the found string, just add it to the vector and continue on, returning the vector when you're done.

If you want to model the standard algorithms, you can also have it take a beginning iterator and an ending iterator instead of the actual container. This will allow you to call it on any type of container, including arrays, with any range in that container to look through.

Taking both points into consideration, you can evolve it into this ([see it work](http://liveworkspace.org/code/e4006e876ada93197f31996762917158)):

```
template <typename Iterator>
std::vector<std::string> findInList(Iterator start, const Iterator end, const std::string &lookFor) {
   std::vector<std::string> ret;

   for (; start != end; ++start)
       if (start->find(lookFor) != std::string::npos)
           ret.emplace_back(*start);

   return ret;
}
```

Again, if not using C++11, `emplace_back` can be swapped out for `push_back`.

Comment: I actually don't want to use vectors, because this is just part of my program so it would change the rest of it

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to substitute arrays for vectors here. The idea is there.

Comment: somehow this looks complicated to me, I like the idea of the codes that Marc Cohen used, but somehow its not working for me

Comment: @MW, My first sample is almost like Marc's. The difference is that Marc's compares the whole of one string to that many beginning characters of the other, whereas `std::string::find` returns the position of where, if anywhere, the substring is found in the bigger one. If it isn't found, `find` returns `npos`. The for loop is just a bit condensed to save space, but a normal one with iterators or indices from 0 to `< searchFrom.size()` works just as well. The vectors *can* be swapped for arrays pretty easily, but if you keep the function, you'll need to know the size. The second is idiomatic.

Comment: @MW, The only thing missing from the first was that you need all of the strings, in which case, you can combine the second's use of `ret` with the first's loop, `emplace_back/push_back`ing  `s` to the vector instead of returning it, and replacing the "not found" return with the vector, which is nicely empty if nothing is found.